# Animating lots of lines in WebGL

Tags: graphics, rendering, webgl

[image: Forest]

I'm trying to animate this scene at 1280x720, 60 fps, antialiased. There are ~500K triangles, two for each tree branch. I can't use `gl.LINES` because [ANGLE](http://alteredqualia.com/tmp/webgl-linewidth-test/).

To get a rough idea about the performance I can expect, I made this test with 1M of random triangles:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Triangles</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            background: #000;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 1280px;
            height: 720px;
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    'use strict';

    const triangleCount = 1e6;
    const antialias = true;

    const generateTriangles = (count, width, height) => {
        const coords = new Float32Array(9 * count);
        for (var i = 0; i < coords.length;) {
            const x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            const y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            const z = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            const theta = Math.random() * Math.PI;

            const ax = 10 * Math.cos(theta) / width;
            const ay = 10 * Math.sin(theta) / height;
            const bx = 10 * Math.cos(theta + 0.3) / width;
            const by = 10 * Math.sin(theta + 0.3) / height;

            coords[i++] = x + ax; coords[i++] = y + ay; coords[i++] = z;
            coords[i++] = x + bx; coords[i++] = y + by; coords[i++] = z;
            coords[i++] = x - ax; coords[i++] = y - ay; coords[i++] = z;

            coords[i++] = x - ax; coords[i++] = y - ay; coords[i++] = z;
            coords[i++] = x - bx; coords[i++] = y - by; coords[i++] = z;
            coords[i++] = x + ax; coords[i++] = y + ay; coords[i++] = z;
        }
        return coords;
    };

    const vertexShaderSource = `
        precision lowp float;
        attribute vec3 aPosition;
        uniform float uWobble;
        void main() {
            float p = 1.0 / (0.3 * aPosition.z - 1.4 + 0.1 * uWobble);
            gl_Position = vec4(p * aPosition.x, p * aPosition.y, aPosition.z, 1.0);
        }
    `;

    const fragmentShaderSource = `
        precision lowp float;
        void main() {
            float z = gl_FragCoord.z;
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.2 * z, z * z, z, 1.0);
        }
    `;

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', {alpha: false, antialias});
    const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
    const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
    const program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    gl.useProgram(program);

    const aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aPosition');
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aVertexPosition);
    const uWobble = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uWobble');
    gl.uniform1f(uWobble, 1);

    const vertices = generateTriangles(triangleCount, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    const render = (timestamp) => {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        gl.uniform1f(uWobble, Math.sin(0.002 * timestamp));
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length / 3);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
    </script>
</body>
```

On a Macbook with Iris 1536 MB I'm getting 12 frames per second. Are there any optimizations I'm missing, such as alternative ways to draw lines, faster antialiasing, some magic flags? Or is this basically the limit of what one can expect from an average GPU?

Comment: You can try using drawElements instead of drawArrays. Should help considerably if you are vertex bound.

Comment: Not sure if I'd call an Intel Iris IGP an *average GPU* but afaik that's what you can expect when you throw 1M triangles at it.

Comment: @WacławJasper using an indexbuffer will help when you're **bandwidth** bound, not vertex bound.

Comment: @LJᛃ It results in faster vertex processing because there are no **duplicates**.

Comment: @WacławJasper Not sure how many duplicates there are in a set of *random generated vertices / triangles*...

Comment: @LJᛃ Presumably OP is _rendering lines as quads/ 2 triangles_? Or Am I misunderstanding the OP?

Comment: Afair he said the performance metrics were gathered *`with 1M of random triangles`*

Comment: Well the question is asking for `animating lots of lines` not `how many random triangles can be drawn`

Comment: Well then if we're talking lines, yes there will be an improvement by using indexbuffers but one needs to take care that indices of related vertices are closely packed within the indexbuffer as post transform caches are not *that* large.

Comment: I get 15 - 60 fps in Chrome, Windows, NVIDEA GeForce 9500 GT (pretty old, 512 MB) 4GB. So I guess it might be worth figuring out what you are really after and measure on more systems

Comment: @WacławJasper right, triangles always come in pairs, so there are 4 vertices for each pair instead of 6. `drawElements` results in a lower frame rate, because vertex indices are 16 bit, and you can only draw 32768 triangles per call.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev `drawElements` is faster than `drawArrays` a vast majority of the time. You pay for 6 extra indices = Uint16Array.BYTE_PER_ELEMENT *6 = 12 bytes but you save 3 * 2 * Float32Array.BYTE_PER_ELEMENT = 24 bytes. Drawing 32767 triangles per call is completely fine and it is what you are suppose to do. Drawing too much per call is actually detrimental to performance.

Comment: "Drawing too much per call is actually detrimental to performance" proof?

Comment: @WacławJasper sounds reasonable, but I mean I've tried both. Here's my test of drawElements https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/165521/draw-elements.html Maybe I'm doing something wrong there. I've tried gl.LINES too, with 2 vertices per line, and got the same frame rate as with drawArrays + triangles, which is kinda strange.

Comment: On my machine a single `drawArrays` call is almost twice as fast as the `drawElements` version.(Intel HD 4000, Chrome Stable, Linux).

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev Try drawing 32767 triangles only and see if it helps because https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#5.18 to "to avoid performance pitfalls in Direct3D based WebGL implementations." Otherwise I have no other ideas and perhaps the other experts will suggest something tangible to try. On my desktop the demo renders at full 60 fps without problems.